# How can I find the Pythagorean hypotenuse which gives a maximum Pythagorean triangles?

Tags: number-theory, maximum-principle, pythagorean-triples

The following Pythagorean hypotenuses have many possibilities of triangles. 
$125$ has three triangles $$35, 120, 125$$
$$44, 117, 125$$
$$75, 100, 125$$
the $365$ has $4$ triangles , $85$ has $4$ triangles , $1125$ has $3$ triangles ,$845$ has $7$ traingles, $1885$ has $13$ traingles ,  $2859545$ has $141$ triangles , and $2859547$ has only one.

We notice that the number of Pythagorean triangle not depend on a clear relation.So, I want to know if there is a specific  Pythagorean hypotenuse which gives a maximum number of triangles?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity

Comment: One can get arbitrarily many such triangles, even primitive triangles, by using a product of many distinct primes of the form $4k+1$. If you don't care about primitive, you can use $5^n$ for large $n$.

Comment: The larger the hypotenuse, the larger i the number of triples that $may$ contain it so thee is no hypotenuse with the $largest$ number of triples.

Answer (score 3):

You got the most efficient case [from Robert in your recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040352/how-many-pythagorean-triangles-which-have-hypotenuse-equal-to-2859545/1040411#1040411). Take the primes $$ 5,13,17,29,37,41, \ldots $$ that are the $$ p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4.  $$
Then take hypoteneuse
$$ H = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdots p_k.  $$
If you allow nonprimitive triangles, the total count of nonzero, ordered, positive triples, giving triangles, is
$$  (3^k - 1)/ 2. $$
If you restrict to primitive triangles, it is just
$$  2^{k-1} $$